# How can I make a JavaScript (with React framework) button create a new instance of a class?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, function, syntax

I am new to web development and I only now make my first page (using ReactJS on top of it), so sorry if this is a noob question. In my page I have created 3 windows which are going to be filled with information later on, and I want the user to be able to make their own ones by clicking a "+" button. Though, for some reason, my code does not work. Even after one clicks at the "+" button, nothing happens. Here's the code of my 'Board' class for demonstration.

```
class Board extends React.Component {
  renderWindow(i) {
    return (
      <Window name={i} />
    );
  }

  handleClick() {
    var test = document.createElement("P");
    test.innerHTML = "this.renderWindow('test-thingy')";
    document.body.appendChild(test);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="info-window">
          {this.renderWindow("Contacts")}
          {this.renderWindow("Accounts")}
          {this.renderWindow("Info")}
        </div>
      <button
        className="button1"
        onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
      >
        {"+"}
      </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I just don't know how to make it respond accordingly, because right now it only creates a text with the quote from test.innerHTML. I have tried several other syntaxes for that line, such as:

```
    test.innerHTML = "{this.renderWindow('test-thingy')}";
```

or

```
    test.innerHTML = "<div> {this.renderWindow('test-thingy')} </div>";
```

or even inverting the " and '. I have been searching ever since for a way, but I am unable to find it. I want it to create a fourth window with the name 'test-thingy'.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the JSX element to be rendered due to change state **as part of the `render` method**.

```js
const WindowComp = ({ name }) => <p>{name}</p>;
class Board extends React.Component {
  state = {
    windowNames: ['Contacts', 'Accounts', 'Info']
  };
  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      windowNames: [...this.state.windowNames, 'test-thingy']
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="info-window">
          {this.state.windowNames.map(
            (name, i) => <WindowComp key={i} name={name} />
          )}
        </div>
      <button
        className="button1"
        onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
      >
        {"+"}
      </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Board />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```

Comment: I didn't get the functionality of this line
`(name, i) => <WindowComp key={i} name={name} />`
and more specifically, the reason you are declaring a key. As of this moment, it is null. Is there a way to fill it from windowNames? Other than that it worked perfectly, and I hadn't the need to declare a WindowComp const because I was using Window which I had created previously.

Comment: The first argument of the `.map` callback is the item being iterated over. For example, in the first iteration, `name` is `windowNames[0]`. The second argument is the index being iterated over, starting at 0 (and 1 on the second iteration, etc). A key is necessary because if you omit it, React shows a warning - see https://adhithiravi.medium.com/why-do-i-need-keys-in-react-lists-dbb522188bbb for details.